# tableView utilities xcode проблема с отображением свойств

Tags: swift, xcode

Кто нибудь подскажет почему я не вижу в utilites свойств tableView, как пример я не могу добавить cell

[image: фото]

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понимаю, что вы хотите увидеть, но возможно вам нужно нажать сюда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А ещё, предполагаю, вам может помочь дерево объектов сториборда. Показал бы кнопку, как его вызвать (хотя, может оно у вас уже и так открыто, только на скрине не видно), но у вас скрин слишком обрезан слева.

Answer (score 0):

Ну окей где тут cell ? в дереве объектов та же беда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я еще не пойму почему там отображаются какие то данные...

Comment: Cell нужно добавить в tableView. Нажмите + и выберите.